# What is the difference between Template Engines and Preprocessors?

Tags: html, templates, template-engine, preprocessor

There are **Template Engines** and there are **Preprocessors**.

**List of some Template Engines**

- Smarty
- Twig
- TinyButStrong

**List of some Preprocessors**

- Haml
- Slim
- Jade / Pug

What exactly is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Haml, Slim, and Jade / Pug don't define themselves as preprocessors or distinct from template engines:

> [Haml](http://haml.info/about.html) is a markup language that’s used to cleanly and simply describe the HTML of any web document without the use of inline code. Haml functions as a replacement for inline page templating systems.
>
> [Slim](http://slim-lang.com/about.html) is a template language...
>
> [Pug](https://github.com/pugjs/pug) is a high performance template engine heavily influenced by Haml and implemented with JavaScript

A *preprocessor* takes input and changes it before it's fed to another program.  A *template engine* might be said to be a type of preprocessor that's specific to documents.  The choice of what to call any of these applications that output HTML is largely semantics.